# slideables queryselector error with dynamic ids

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dynamic

I am trying to use this angular slide-toggle directive on github: https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables

It says it supports dynamic ids like id="foo_{{$index}}" but it does not provide a working example. I tried making one and I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

I know typeError has to do with jQuery loading before the script, but since this angular is handling the jQuery, I am not sure how to make this persons code do what it's supposed to.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="row in data">
        <span slide-toggle="#row_{{$index}}" >expand row #{{$index}}.</span>
        <div id="row_{{$index}}" class="slideable">
            <p>How are YOU doing?</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

my dynamic mod that consoles the error: http://jsfiddle.net/3sVz8/486/

if this can work, I also need it to use something like id="foo_{{item.id}}" instead of the typical $index

Comment: updated: http://jsfiddle.net/3sVz8/880/ thanks codewizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error not because of your id's but becuase you aren't defining what "target" is....

```
    element.bind('click', function() {
        var content = target.querySelector('.slideable_content');
        if(!attrs.expanded) {
            content.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)';
            var y = content.clientHeight;
            content.style.border = 0;
            target.style.height = y + 'px';
        } else {
            target.style.height = '0px';
        }
    attrs.expanded = !attrs.expanded;
});
```

When you are setting var content, target isn't being passed or defined anywhere.. Do you want the event target? You'll have to pass event into you're callback function in-order to access it. Even so in-order to use querySelector you'd have to define target as document (var target = document) because querySelector is a method of the document object.

[Read more about querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) the first sentence says it all "Returns the first element within the document", which means you always use querySelector as so `document.querySelector(selectors);`